# Stack reversal algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, stack

I saw an algorithm for reversing stack without using any other stack. I made the C program as per the algorithm, but I could not really understand how does it work. Please help me explain the below code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void push(int item);
int pop();
void display();
void reverseStack();
void insertAtBottom(int);
typedef struct stack
{
    int data;
    struct stack* next;
} stack;
stack* top=NULL;
int main()
{
    push(5);
    push(13);
    push(16);
    push(17);
    display();
    pop();
    printf("Display before reversal\n");
    display();
    reverseStack();
    printf("Display after reversal\n");
    display();
    return 0;
}
void push(int data)
{
    stack* temp = malloc(sizeof(stack));
    temp->next=top;
    temp->data  = data;
    top = temp;
}
int pop()
{
    int a;
    stack* temp;
    temp = top;
    if(top == NULL)
        return -1;
    //printf("popped item=%d\n", temp->data);
    a = temp->data;
    top = top->next;
    free(temp);
    return a;
}
void display()
{
    stack* temp = top;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

void reverseStack()
{

    int data ;
    if(top != NULL)
    {
        data = pop();
        reverseStack();
        insertAtBottom(data);
    }
}

void insertAtBottom(int data)
{
    int a;
    if(top==NULL)
    {
        push(data);
        return;
    }
    a = pop();
    insertAtBottom(data);
    push(a);

}
```

The above program works as expected. But how does the algorithm working, I am not sure. Please explain.

Comment: Wait, are you saying that you wrote the program but can't understand how it works?

Comment: I have seen the algorithm. Then I just made the C program which can implement the algorithm.

Comment: That algorithm does use another stack: the call stack.

Comment: Reversing a stack without using extra "storage" has been asked about many times, this is the oldest thatvI know about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072903/invert-a-stack-without-using-extra-data-structures

Comment: I supposed just doing it [the old fashioned way](http://pastebin.com/crCZrJSM) is out of the question or off the allowable radar?

Comment: Add calls to `display` at suitable places and see if the state of the stack helps explain how the algorithm works. http://ideone.com/ZtQ2eu

Answer (score 1):

The key function here is function `insertAtBottom`

```
void insertAtBottom(int data)
{
    int a;
    if(top==NULL)
    {
        push(data);
        return;
    }
    a = pop();
    insertAtBottom(data);
    push(a);

}
```

It inserts a data on the bottom of the stack instead of on the top of the stack. How does it works? It recursively pops all elements from the stack and when at last the stack is empty it adds the new element:

```
if(top==NULL)
{
     push(data);
     return;
}
```

and then it restores all existent elements in the order in which they were on the stack

```
a = pop();
/*insertAtBottom(data);*/
push(a);
```

I commented the middle statement that it would be more clear.

On the other hand function `reverseStack`

```
void reverseStack()
{

    int data ;
    if(top != NULL)
    {
        data = pop();
        reverseStack();
        insertAtBottom(data);
    }
}
```

inserts elements on the bottom of the stack calling function  `insertAtBottom`

Let assume that the stack has values

top: 1
2
3
4
bottom: 5

The function at first recursively pops all elements from the stack

Then it push the last element in the stack

```
top->bottom: 5
```

---

Then it insert on the bottom the previous element

```
top: 5
bottom: 4
----------
```

And so on

```
top:5
4
bottom: 3
----------

top: 5
4
3
bottom: 2
----------

top: 5
4
3
2
bottom: 1
----------
```

Comment: i do not think that it is a wise solution to iterate container of unknown size recursively. That will cause stack overflows. Beside of this its a nice educative solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need another Stack to reverse your stack. You can do this in one iterating pass over your structure and you only need a few local variables to exchange the next pointers:

```
void reverseStack()
{
    stack* it = top->next;
    top->next = NULL;
    while(it!=NULL)
    {   
        stack* temp = it->next;
        it->next = top;
        top = it;
        it = temp;
    }
}
```

PS: adding sanity checks for empty stack is up to the TO.